# Passing values between classes

Tags: java, swing, oop

I have a JPanel form which contains a JList and some JButton.
The JPanel looks like this

[image]

When I click the Add List button, a separate JFrame form is displayed. 
The JFrame form will look like this

[image]

When the add button on the JFrame is clicked, I need to add the value of the JTextfield (named List Name) to the JList on the previous JPanel. I wonder how to pass the value from the JFrame to the JPanel? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Here is a code of the JPanel form (using Designer GUI)

```
package multimediaproject;

public class musicPlayerPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    public musicPlayerPanel() {       
        initComponents();   
    }

    private void initComponents() {
          //...here is the generated code by using designer GUI       
    }                      

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    //..generated code
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Here is the code of JFrame form (using Designer GUI)

```
package multimediaproject;

public class addListFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public addListFrame() {
        initComponents();

        this.setLocation(515, 0);
        setVisible(true);        
    }

    private void initComponents() {
    //..here is the generated code by using Designer GUI       
    }                       

    private void addBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                      
        //some validation
        if(...)
        {
            //validation
        }

        else
        {
           //IF VALUE IS CORRECT, ADD the List Name JTextfield value to the JList on the previous JPanel

          errorMessage.setText("");
        }

}                                      

public static void main(String args[]) {

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new addListFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    //....generated code
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: *"Any suggestion would be appreciated."*  1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Please don't forget to add a '?' to questions!  Some people do a search in the page for '?' and if none exists in the 'question' go directly to the next (actual) question in line. 3)  Java classes start with a capital letter.  Use it. 4) Don't extend frame/panel etc., I guess that is 'your IDE talking'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE** with your code.

You can take advantage of `PropertyChangeListener` and `PropertyChangeSupport` (This classes implements Observer Pattern).

I give you an example you for guidance:

```
public class MusicPlayerPanel extends JPanel {

private JList list;
private JButton addButton;
private PropertyChangeListener listener = new MyPropertyChangeListener();

//..in some place
addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        JFrame form = new FrameForm();
        form.addPropertyChangeListener(FrameForm.BUTTON_CLICKED,listener);
        form.setVisible(true);
  }

});

//in another place

private class MyPropertyChangeListener implements PropertyChangeListener{

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt){
         if(evt == null)
              return;

        if(evt.getPropertyName().equals(FrameForm.BUTTON_CLICKED)){
           String value = (String) evt.getNewValue();
           ((DefaultListModel)list.getModel()).addElement(value); 
        }

    }

}


}
```

And the frame form like this:

```
public class AddListFrame extends JFrame{


 private JTextField textfield;
 private JButton submitButton;
 public static final String BUTTON_CLICKED ="buttonClicked";

 // in some place
   submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
               firePropertyChange(BUTTON_CLICKED,null,textfield.getText());
         }

    });
}
```

**Note**: In java by convention, classes start with uppercase and follow a camel style. This is very important for readability.

Comment: `Frameform  form=new Frameform(); form.addPropertyChangeListener(FrameForm.BUTTON_CLICKED,listener);`What if the frame form is already auto generated by netbeans (because I use designer GUI to create the frame)? Shoul I add a new constructor with parameter to that frame?

Comment: I code the `new addListFrame(); this.addPropertyChangeListener();` 
on the JPanel form now. How can the "this" thing refer to another created JFrame? Shouldn't it refer to the JPanel now? I'm a java beginner, sorry.

Comment: @SalacceoVanz i edit answer hope it helps you, let me know if you don't understand something

Comment: `if(evt.getPropertyName(FrameForm.BUTTON_CLICKED))` This code produce an error : Method getPropertyName required no arguments, found String

Comment: @SalacceoVanz i watch your code, you have some serious **potential** bugs, 1st) don't use Vector , use `ArrayList`, 2nd)This is the most important. You are overriding `validate()`, that is a method that it's called all the time that's why your gui is not visible, call it with another name, 3rd) Your musicPanel is creating a JFrame everytime is clicked i don't know if you want this 4th) Follow java code conventions, classes start with upperCase!!

Comment: thx for helping me further, do you know how to solve the third bug?

Answer (score 0):

> *"when I click the add button, **a separate jFrame form is displayed. The jFrame contain a jTextfield and a submit button."***

Did you *seriously* create an entirely new `JFrame` for a `JTextField` and a `JButton`?!

Have you not heard of `JOptionPane`? That's exactly what you are trying to replicate.  The only code you need is this:

```
String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(component, message);    
model.addElement(s);
```

The first line will cover all your code for your custom `JFrame`.

Take a look at this example

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JOPDemo extends JPanel {

    JList list;
    JButton button = new JButton("Add Name");
    String name;
    DefaultListModel model;

    public JOPDemo() {
        model = new DefaultListModel();
        list = new JList(model);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(list, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);



        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Enter a name");
                model.addElement(name);
            }
        });
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(300, 300);

    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new JOPDemo());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Edit**

What you can do is have an inner class which is your JFrame. Personally, I'd go with a JDialog though.

From comment: Have your frame as an inner class of your main class. That way it can access all the variables from your main class. You can have a String listName also in the GUI class. From the other frame when you hit add, it sets the listName in GUI class, then adds to the list.

```
public class GUI {
    String listName;
    JList list;
    InnerFrame inner = new InnerFrame();

    private class InnerFrame extends JFrame {
        JButton addButton;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I simplified the problem, actually the frame contains something like this http://imgur.com/fNhv0tB

Comment: Is that the frame that pops up? And the List Name is the text field you're referring to?

Comment: Yes, it is a separate JFrame which is popup (I create that JFrame with designer GUI), and the list name is the text field I'm referring to.

Comment: Have you frame as an inner class of your main class. That way it can access all the variables from your main class. You can have a String `listName`  also in the GUI class. From the other frame when you hit add, it sets the listName in GUI class, then adds to the list

Comment: What if the frame form is created by using Designer GUI? It generated a long messy code, so I make it separate.

Comment: @SalacceoVanz i don't know why you don't follow my answer cause it what you need.. and is in a decoupled way, i should edit cause you add your code i was guessing but the idea is the same

Comment: @nachokk sorry I still need time to learn your code and implement it on mine, but still thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

OK.This is easy if i understand your problem.
Step 1:Create setter and getter for your JList object reference.
Step 2:On button click , when you open new JFrame pass your panel reference in constructor of class which inherits JFrame.
Step 3:By doing this you are able to call getter method on panel reference.
Step 4:Now you have reference of JList,do what you want.

I hope this is best solution of your problem

Comment: thx for the respone, by the way how to add a setter to the JList object?

Comment: ok.Make a setter /getter method for JList object in which class where you make JPanel.